# qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity

Tags: c++

Could anyone help me understand why the below code doesn't compile (VS2010) when the getters are const ?

Here's the test code:

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

class socket {
public:

    // setter - throw exception version
void non_blocking(bool mode)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // getter - error code version      
    bool non_blocking(boost::system::error_code& ec) const
    {
        // ...
    }

    // setter - error code version
void non_blocking(bool mode, boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // getter - throw exception version    
    bool non_blocking() const
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    socket s;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    bool result = s.non_blocking(ec);

    return 0;
}
```

I know that boost::system::error_code is convertible to bool but can't understand why the const cause the ambiguity. Here's the error message from VS2010:

```
1>c:\projects\pcap++\trunk\main.cpp(145): error C2666: 'socket::non_blocking' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
1>          c:\projects\pcap++\trunk\main.cpp(134): could be 'bool socket::non_blocking(boost::system::error_code &) const'
1>          c:\projects\pcap++\trunk\main.cpp(129): or       'void socket::non_blocking(bool)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(boost::system::error_code)'
1>          note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity
```

Comment: If `s` was `const`, there would have been no ambiguity, but it is not, and both functions could be used. I wonder why you have the first function (the one with `bool`), though.

Comment: It looks odd. Are you calling `void non_blocking` inside `bool non_blocking`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: How about `bool result = s.non_blocking(ec);`? How is this ambiguous? Obviously compiler cannot match with `void non_blocking(bool)`.

Comment: `boost::system::error_code` is convertible to `bool` and (I think) return type is not used in lookup.

Comment: I've edited the code so I think it will give better view. The purpose is to have two versions of getter/setters: a) throw exception, b) error code. Just like it is in boost::asio.

Comment: @sad_man, the compiler is visual studio. What do you expect? But seriously, as hmjd said also, return value is by no means part of function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of overload resolution, the parameter list of the two overloads are `class socket &, bool` and `const class socket &, boost::system::error_code &`.

The calling parameters are `class socket &, boost::system::error_code &`

To match the first overload, the following conversion is needed:

```
1.
class socket &              -> no conversion
bool                        -> user defined conversion
2.
class socket &              -> qualification conversion
boost::system::error_code & -> no conversion
```

In C++0x 13.3.3p1 :

> Define ICSi(F) as follows:
>
> — if F is a static member function, ICS1(F) is defined such that
>   ICS1(F) is neither better nor worse than ICS1(G) for any function G,
>   and, symmetrically, ICS1(G) is neither better nor worse than
>   ICS1(F); otherwise,
>
> — let ICSi(F) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts
>   the i-th argument in the list to the type of the i-th parameter of
>   viable function F. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences
>   and
>   13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than
>   another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function F2 if **for all arguments
>   i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2)**, and then
>
> ....

From this, we can see the neither of the match of the two overloads fits this requirement. For the one function, one conversion sequence is better and one conversion is worse than the corresponding conversion sequence of the other function, so the viable function cannot be determined.

If the second overload is not `const`, then the conversion sequence for the second overload does not need any conversion (both are identical), so this is better than the other overload, thus no ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Two equally-ranked conversions are possible:

- `socket &` → `socket const &`
- `boost::system::error_code` → `bool`

You can disambiguate manually:

```
bool result = static_cast<socket const &>(s).non_blocking(ec);

s.non_blocking(bool(ec));
```

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I know how to disambiquate it manually. What I wonder is why there's no ambiguity when getters are no const.

Comment: @bart: In that case one is a *better* match than the other.

Comment: Could anyone give me a reference to c++ standard explaining this behavior ?